# Is a projective reference in Pn needed for an affine subspace to be set (by means of a group action)?

Tags: group-actions, projective-space, affine-geometry

Assuming a group action $A \times V \rightarrow{A}$ to set an affine space $A$, and assuming that the space $V$ is a translation-space, that is a vector space; then, is a projective reference needed (beforehand) in order to turn points into vectors on a given coordinate within the quotient space (projective space) and allowing to take subspaces' (hyperplanes') translations?

Thanks you in advance.

Comment: No, it's not needed. The affine action perfectly describes the affine space.

Comment: thanks! if i may, let me ask you an additional elementary question: how many projective points are needed to bring an affine-reference (for instance, in the case of an affine plane $A^{2}$ within some projective space $P^{n}$? greetings